# Elimination of image blurring using noise model restoration techniques

Tags: image-processing, image-restoration

How can the blurring be eliminated from image using the noise model restoration process techniques?

To my knowledge the answer must be filter.If yes,then which filter is used?

Comment: The question isn't clear. D you mean to apply a restoration of blurred image in the presence of noise?

Comment: The question is asking for the techniques of restoration model to  remove the blurring in an image.

Comment: What's the purpose of mentioning noise?